# Using ?? operator with different types

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I Have something like this in my code when composing SQL query

```
if (query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchValue2Or != null)
                parameters.Add($"@matchValue2Or{i}", query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchValue2Or);
            else
                parameters.Add($"@matchValue2Or{i}", DBNull.Value);
```

And I want It to be like

```
parameters.Add($"@matchValue2Or{i}", query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchValue2Or ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Compiler doesn't let me run this. I tried casting to object DBNull.Value - I ended up with runtime exception, the same thing when casting other one

Comment: Assuming you are using a DbCommand parameters, the second argument is the type, not the value.

Comment: What is exception message and stacktrace?

Comment: OP the coalesce expects to see both the same type. Cast them both to object, if you must.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ the method that accepts a name and value is `AddWithValue`, which isn't very robust. `Add` doesn't pass values. Unless you refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that would generate compiler warnings ?

Comment: Define the command and parameters with proper sizes and types first, *then* pass the values. `Add(string,Object)` is deprecated and the `AddWithValue` can infer the wrong types and sizes. You can create the command instance once and reuse it with different connections and values

Comment: I add them to Dictionary<string, object> then pass it further

Answer (score 1):

The types must be the same, but they can be `object` so you can cast the value to `object`

```
parameters.Add($"@matchValue2Or{i}", query.BlackWhiteListFieldMatchProxy[i].MatchValue2Or as object ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: `Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value)`. That method is [obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx). `AddWithValue` isn't great either as it infers types and sizes that may be not match the table and cause unexpected results, eg decimals stored with the wrong number of digits, truncated or padded strings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 10x for the info, I updated the answer

Comment: I add them to Dictionary<string, object> then pass it further

Comment: @RostyslavFedyk the method the value is passed to makes no difference, I'm starting to regret including it in the answer, the important part is the `as object`